# JSP Site web.xml issue Page not found for url-pattern /MyController in sevlet-mapping

Tags: servlets, web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pk.MyController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have this configuration, but unable to access `hzhfyp.com/MyController` (`PAGE NOT FOUND`)

The Path for `MyController` servelet is `WEB-INF/classes/com/pk/MyController.class`

Although `index.jsp` is loaded accuratelty. Demo here `http://hzhfyp.com/` Clicking any button will generate js error visible in Firebug(firefox) as Page not Found.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are case sensitive. You've mapped it on `/MyController` with `M`, but your jQuery code is calling it by `/myController` with `m`. Fix it accordingly.

As to the servlet returing a 404 in spite of the correct URL, this can happen when the servlet failed to initialize or when you didn't deploy the correct `web.xml` at all. Read the server startup logs for any errors during servlet initialization and verify if you're deploying with the right `web.xml`.

Comment: Sorry i change it in last moment before copy paste, it was /myController earlier. I change it to /myController now, but still no findings, ANy further help.

Comment: http://hzhfyp.com/myController 404 Not Found
  
HeadersPostResponseHTML

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /myController was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: I am testing on web server. how to check ? from CPanel??

Comment: I have no idea what hosting you're using and I have no idea what you mean with "CPanel". Just contact your hosting support. Does it work when you run it locally?

Comment: Cpanel control panel for webserver, here i checked the logs, which display page not found errors but i can not view tomcat server log. Yes, on local machine it works, but online it not mapped correctly. ANyway Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Contact your hosting support and ask how to view tomcat logs. In future, consider dedicated, colocated or clustered hosting which is really designed for JSP/Servlet. Google Appengine maybe? After googling, the Cpanel thing seems to be specific to elcheapo PHP hostings.